# $ \bigcap\limits_{x\in A} E_x=\{\}$ How does the proof hold.

Tags: general-topology

Let A be the set defined as $A=\{x \in \mathbb{R}:0<x\leq 1)\}$. $\forall x \in A $ ,

$E_x =\{y \in \mathbb{R}:0<y<x\}$

Then $ {\bigcap\limits_{x\in A} } E_x=\{\}$

Proof

$\forall y>0,   y\notin\ E_x$ if  $x<y.$

Hence $y\notin \bigcap\limits_{x\in A} E_x$

Now my problem with this is that if y>x then we are not operating with the set $E_x$ anymore, so how could this be a proof. What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So $A = (0,1]$ and $E_x  =(0,x)$. The statement is an exercise in careful reading and translating it to a logical statement.

The claim is $\bigcap_{x \in A} E_x = \emptyset$.

By definition of the intersection, $p \in \bigcap_{x \in A} E_x$ iff

$$\forall x \in A: p \in E_x$$
the definition of $E_x$ then tell us:

$$\forall x \in A: 0 < p < x$$

by definition of $A$:

$$\forall x \in (0,1]: 0 < p <x$$

Because all $E_x \subseteq (0,1]$ our supposed $p$ lies in $(0,1]$ as well.
Now we can take $x = \frac{p}{2} \in A$ in particular.
But then the last statement becomes $0 < p < \frac{p}{2}$, which is false for all $p$.

This shows that no point $p\in \mathbb{R}$ lies in the intersection $\bigcap_{x \in A} E_x$.

Comment: Hm,  why does A include zero as x had to be larger than zero. Not larger and equal to.

Comment: Yes, Henno it appears you've misread the definition of $A $.

Comment: @ALEXANDER yes, that is the more interesting case, I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

> Now my problem with this is that if y>x then we are not operating with the set  $E_x$ anymore, so how could this be a proof. What am I missing?

That is not a problem; that is what you require.   If there is some $x$ in $A$, such that $y$ is not in *that* $E_x$, then $y$ is not in the *intersection* of *all* $E_x$ (over $x\in A$).   If that happens to be so for every real $y$ then the intersection is empty.

---

$y\in \bigcap_{x\in A} E_x$ is equivalent to $\forall x~\big((0<x\leqslant 1)\to(0<y<x)\big)$. $~$ I assert that this is false for any real value, $y$, because either that $y$ will be at most $0$, or else there is an $x$ in the interval that is not greater than $y$. $~$ Since the statement holds for no such $y$, therefore $\bigcap_{x\in A} E_x$ is an empty set.

via:

$A=\{x\in \Bbb R: 0< x\leq 1\} = (0;1]$

$E_x=\{y\in \Bbb R:0<y<x\} = (0;x)$

$\therefore~\bigcap_{x\in A} E_x = \{y\in\Bbb R: \forall x\in A:y\in E_x\}= \{y\in\Bbb R: \forall x\in (0;1]:y\in(0;x)\} =\{\}$